# How to quickly navigate from to the "next page" when using numbered items (ie Jenkins logs)

Tags: javascript, jenkins, logging, cross-browser

I often view the log of a Jenkins run. The jobs are sequentially numbered and URLs look like
`http://{myJenkins-Instance}/job/{jobName}/{Number}/console`

After looking at the result of one job, I'd like to easily see the next one (aka "increment the counter"). And after editing a URL for the 100th time I thought it would be nice if this could be automated.

Comment: Isn't there a next / previous build buttons on the left margin? There is for me. Click, click.

Comment: Eg: https://ci.jenkins.io/job/Core/job/jenkins/job/master/4174/

Comment: Exactly, URLs like that.

Comment: Duh  - the regex only dealt with numbers embedded in `/` - I've updated it so that the number can also be at the end, as in your case.

Comment: @IanW  , I notice I didn't fully understand your point about the next / previous buttons. I'm mainly interested in directly getting into the "raw" logs (as you can see from the URL I was using) - these console pages do not have such navigation (and ofc that's not possible there), so such an "external" manipulation of the URL seemed the only way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did not find browser plugins to do this - so I rolled my own.
Well, it's not a plugin - it's a simple URL that you can add to your bookmarks (list or bar). I've put it into the bar, so it's always visible and allows me to easily switch one "page" forward:

`javascript:  t= window.location.href;console.log(t);n=t.replace(/\/(\d+)+(?:\/|$)/g, function(match, number) {return '/' + (parseInt(number)+1) + '/';});window.location.href=n;`

I found it very useful, so I'm sharing it here - hopefully it'll help someone else ;)